# Can I split a job into multiple jobs that are all guaranteed to run on the same machine?

Tags: jenkins

I have a long (2+ hours) jenkins job that has multiple build steps.

I would like to have a easy way of telling how far along the build is.   I would like some sort of "green light" for each build step to know when each step finished succesfully.

In order to do that, I was thinking of breaking the build up into multiple smaller jobs.  If I do that, is it possible in Jenkins to set it up so that these smaller jobs all are run one after another, all on the same Jenkins node and workspace?   I want them to run on the same machine, immediately after one another, so that I don't have to worry about copying gigabytes of data around as artifacts.

Let's say that I break it into 3 jobs: jobA, jobB, and jobC.  jobA runs on whichever machine in my build pool is currently avilable.  As soon as jobA is done, jobB starts up on that same machine, not giving any other job a chance to run.  After jobB is done, jobC likewise is run.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Build-pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) plugin lets you create a new to visualize what is being built based on upstream downstream relationship.

For your case you can create the build steps as different jobs and connect them in post build actions.

The view you created for pipeline will show each step and its progress.

Comment: Will it allow me to ensure that the jobs connected in the post build actions will run immediately on the same machine?

Comment: you can configure the jobs to run on a selected slave, you can mark all the 3 jobs to run on the same slave machine. Also, change the settings for the slave node to run jobs that are labelled

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the job to run on the same node is one of the advanced options when using the Parameterized Trigger plugin.